# I want to change the number of items with lineupemate of orderupdate

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to change the number of items with lineupemate of orderupdate.

Now we set the values ​​as follows.

```
"lineItemUpdates": {
  "item id": {
   "extension":{
    "@type":"types.example.com/standard/id",
    "quantity":0
   }
  },
 },
```

I do not know how to set extention type and other fiel.

Please tell me the solution.

Comment: I want to change the number of items with lineitemupdates of orderupdate.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question and [edit] your question instead of adding a comment: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* ([I downvoted because there is no code](//idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**